# How would you solve for S(t) in the equation

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Solve for $S (t)$ in the equation

$$-c \, t = \log S(t)$$

where $t$ is time and $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

$$-ct=\log S(t)$$
take $e$ for both sides
$$e^{-ct}=S(t)$$